# Scope для уровня изоляции транзакций

Tags: sql

Доброго времени суток. Есть инструкция sql **set transaction isolation level**. А какова у этой инструкции область действия? Вот я е применил, и когда заканчивается ее действие? Ведь в sql нет оператора фигурных скобок (**{}**) с помощью которого можно в языках типа java, C# или С++ определить область видимости переменной. Заранее спасибо

Comment: [Одновременно может быть установлен только один параметр уровня изоляции, который продолжает действовать для текущего соединения до тех пор, пока не будет явно изменен.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173763(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: @YuraIvanov: по-моему заслуживает того, чтобы быть ответом, а не комментарием. JuniorThree: на будущее, указывайте, с какой СУБД работаете, плиз (MSSQL? MySQL?)

Comment: @Nickolay ссылка копипаста из документации намекает, что информация гуглится и перепечатывать всю статью для неизвестной субд, да, смысла нет...

Answer (score 0):

SQL стандарт описывает это выражение в части E152. Публично действующие стандарты недоступны, но можно свободно читать [черновые версии стандартов](https://www.wiscorp.com/SQLStandards.html).

> Set the characteristics of the next SQL-transaction for the SQL-agent.
>
> NOTE 522 — This statement has no effect on any SQL-transactions subsequent to the next SQL-transaction.

По стандарту действует на последующую транзакцию и прекращает действие сразу после неё.

Ну стандарт - стандартом, а конкретные реализации могут иметь своё мнение. (проверено только для PostgreSQL, для остальных интерпретация мануала по приведённой ссылке)

### [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-set-transaction.html)

Действует только на текущую транзакцию, может вызываться только после старта транзакции и перед каким-либо запросом манипулирующим данными. Вне открытой транзакции эффекта не имеет и выдаёт предупреждение об этом при использовании.

```
begin;
set transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ ;
-- any queries
```

### [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-transaction.html)

Описание соответствует стандарту, без указания GLOBAL или SESSION выражение действует на следующую транзакцию и только на неё.

### [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/statements_10005.htm#SQLRF01705)

Выражение выставляет параметры транзакции и непосредственно начинает транзакцию. Действует только на эту транзакцию.

### [MS SQL](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql)

Продолжает действовать для текущего соединения до тех пор, пока не будет явно изменен.

### SQLite

Не поддерживает команду вовсе.

```
sqlite> set transaction isolation level REPEATABLE READ ;
Error: near "set": syntax error
```